# NatSpec Format is `msg.sender` available?

Tags: solidity, natspec

Want to know if when documenting a function the `msg.sender` is available for NatSpec [dynamic expressions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/natspec-format.html?highlight=documentation#dynamic-expressions)

```
contract Foo {

  /**
  * @notice This will foo the `msg.sender`
  */
  function foo() external {
    //... foo the sender
  }
}
```